# Animate non-fixed width

Tags: wpf

I've been working with WPF for some time. 
I'm searching for a way to animate a non-fixed width of elements with double animation, it seems that i can't give `From="0" To="*"` or `From="0" To="Auto"` for `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"`.

I assume i have to work with precenteges, something like:

```
<DoubleAnimation ... ... ... From="0%" To="100%"
```

I Know there is a way to do it with VisualStateManager, if this is the only option - i would appreciate a reference of on how to do it.

Thanx alot
Gili

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to animate `Height` or `Width` without setting a fixed value, as when collapsing/expanding a panel, I manage to do it by animating `MinWidth`, `MinHeight`, `MaxWidth`, and `MaxHeight` properties instead.

You might be able to do the same, but without more specifics I can't go beyond that.